# CouchDB : How should I design the data structure? Is there something like folder, cabinet or drawer to keep things tidy?

Tags: database-design, couchdb

I have been hearing about CouchDB & nosql dbs for a while, finally got time to dig a bit more. I chose Couch mainly because of the http api as js is my most familiar language and I can do things without my server fellows.

By diving into the CouchDB for a whole day, and going through the guide briefly, one question came up: How should I structure my data?

Lets say, we have 3 people and 3 books: Tom, Mike & Marry; book1, book2 & book3.
Is there anything that lets you put different types into different categories? Like:

folder people

```
{name:'Tom'}
{name:'Mike'}
{name:'Marry'}
```

folder book

```
{name:'book1'} 
{name:'book2'} 
{name:'book3'}
```

As I found out that it'll be very hard for views for different databases, it will not be practical to put them in different databases. All I can figure out maybe:

```
{type:'people',name:'Tom'}
{type:'people',name:'Mike'}
{type:'people',name:'Marry'}
{type:'book',name:'book1'} 
{type:'book',name:'book2'} 
{type:'book',name:'book3'}
```

But again, even if this will be the only solution, using strings for the type doesn't seem to be a good idea; there should be something like 'cost' to maintain the types really.

Comment: The idea of using a type field is the most common solution, I think. Why do you think using strings is not a good idea? Another option would be to check for the existance of certain fields to figure out which type it is. For example, a book will have an isbn field but a person won't.